# Adding a bunch of items to ArrayList correctly

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a major problem with how I am adding items to my list. In the for loop I have constructed, I am not sure how to continually add elements to the list. I keep adding only one element which overwrites the last element in the list. So if I was to add 2 elements to my list, after the loop has finished, my array list size will be 1. I'm not sure how to add items properly. I know exactly where the problem lies but am struggling to find any clever way of adding correctly. Will really appreciate any help

```
tasklist = db.getAllTasks();
    locationlist = db.getAllLocations();

    for (int i = 0; i < locationlist.size(); i++) {
    task_location_list = db.getAllTasksbyLocation(locationlist.get(i)
                .getAddress());


        for (Task task : task_location_list) {
            task_location_list.add(task);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you definitely shouldnt be adding to the same list that you then reload. More to the point, why are you adding elements on a list to itself.

Comment: you have a loop on task_location_list and adding item in the same

Comment: What are you *trying* to do? What items should be added to what list? Can you describe your problem, perhaps without code?

Comment: I can see a few mistakes, but without knowing what you are trying to achieve, people will struggle to answer. `tasklist` is never used.. what list are you trying to build

Comment: Sorry If im being unclear. I have a list of tasks, and a list of locations. I have a database that stores the ID's of both location and tasks linked together. I want to put the tasks that have locations into one list. So i am trying to copy all tasks that have a location into one list

Comment: That comment there is useful in your question to give us an idea of what you are trying to achieve, and hence answer it directly. :) Glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
 task_location_list =new ArrayList<Task>();
 for (int i = 0; i < locationlist.size(); i++) {
    task_location_list .addAll(db.getAllTasksbyLocation(locationlist.get(i)
                .getAddress()));

    }
```

Comment: Thats probably what hes trying to do. +1. Allthough i dont see how it differs from `getAllTasks` , since he calls that on every location

Comment: I'm not very good with programming and I really appreciate the feedback. I probably should have got this. Thank you for the answer.